# R: Find max/min of list of columns in data frame

Tags: r

Suppose I have a list of column names as a vector:

```
vec=c("C1" , "C2" ,"C3").
```

I know for a fact that these column names come from a data frame df:

```
df:

C1 C2 C3 C4 C5
1   2  3  4  5
1   4  3  5  6
3   2  4  1  3
```

How can I find the maximum value of each column in vec, looking at their values in df. For example, something like:

```
boostedMax(vec, df, na.rm=T)
```

Obviously that doesnt work, but the idea is that boostedMax takes a vector of column names and a data frame where the columns are, and returns the max values from these columns. In this example, it would return the vector:

```
(3,4,4)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Edited to provide an example dataframe.

Comment: `sapply(df[vec], max, na.rm = T)`

Comment: When providing example data, it's nice to make it copy/pasteable. You can do this by including the code to create the data frame or by posting `dput(df)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
vec=c("C1" , "C2" ,"C3")

C1 C2 C3 C4 C5
1   2  3  4  5
1   4  3  5  6
3   2  4  1  3

df <- read.table(con<-file("clipboard"), header = T)
df

apply(df[,vec],2,max)
```

> ```
> C1 C2 C3 
>  3  4  4
> ```

or

```
for(i in vec){
  print(max(df[,i]))
}
```

> ```
> [1] 3
> [1] 4
> [1] 4
> ```

or

```
sapply(df[,vec],max)
```

> ```
> C1 C2 C3 
>  3  4  4
> ```

If you think that some levels of `vec` may not be in `df` you can do `df[,colnames(df) %in% vec]` instead of `df[,vec]`

Comment: `apply` is worse than `sapply` for this (Gregor's comment), as it could corrupt orderings, e.g., if you have mixed char and num columns.

Comment: Hm, turns out I was wrong anyways. I thought `apply` would screw this up, but somehow it doesn't: `DF = data.frame(a = c(2.2, 11, 1), b = c("A", "B", "C")); apply(DF, 2, max)`

Comment: @RajRaina Glad to hear it. if you think that some levels of `vec` may not be in `df` you can do `df[,colnames(df) %in% vec]`

Answer (score 1):

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1:4, NA), b = 6:10, c = 11:15)
d <- colnames(df)[1:2]
sapply(df[d], max, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `colMaxs` from `matrixStats` after converting the subset of dataset to `matrix`

```
library(matrixStats)
colMaxs(as.matrix(df[vec]))
#[1] 3 4 4
```

---

Or another option is `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    summarise_each_(funs(max), vec)
#  C1 C2 C3
#1  3  4  4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dat <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3),b=c(2,3,4),c=c(3,4,5))
> dat
  a b c
1 1 2 3
2 2 3 4
3 3 4 5

> sapply(dat, max, na.rm = TRUE)
a b c 
3 4 5
```